# Regex to validate number range in string input

Tags: java, regex

I have one scenario to validate a network VLAN range (1 to 4094). Input will be in string format.
Ex : 50-60,65,2345-3010

Can someone suggest how to check if the input numbers are within the given range?

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. Use [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to parse the integers. Then test if the values are in range.

Answer (score 0):

```
            int highRange = 4094;
            int lowRange =1;
            String str = "50-60,65,2345-3010,4000-5100";
            String[] comma = str.split(",");
            for(int k=highRange; k>lowRange;k--){
                for (int i = 0; i < comma.length; i++) {
                    int ab = comma[i].indexOf("-");
                    if(ab>0){
                        String[] value = comma[i].split("-");
                        for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
                            if(k == Integer.parseInt(value[j])){
                                System.out.println(value[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(k == Integer.parseInt(comma[i])){
                            System.out.println(comma[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

output:

4000
3010
2345
65
60
50
```